# OpenLayers can't draw geoJSON on map

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I'm trying to draw some simple shapes (mostly lines) on a Open Street Map using OpenLayers 3. The code I’m using is almost directly copied from an [example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/geojson.html) on their site, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(arr[i].geoJSON)
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Where `styleFunction` is the same function as in the example, and `arr[i].geoJSON` is a completely valid geoJSON object.

The problem is, that it doesn't draw anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to create a JSFiddle showing the problem to enable others to investigate.

Comment: Don't forget the coordinates on your geojson must be in EPSG:3857 and this projection must be defined in your json like in the example.            Otherwise you can specify options in the format object to reproject the data see the api: http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to provide options to the `readFeatures` method. GeoJSON projection is generally using 4326 while most web map are generally in 3857.

Try to call:

```
(new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(arr[i].geoJSON,{
    featureProjection:"EPSG:3857"
});
```